# Return array of Mat object to Java

Tags: java, android, opencv, java-native-interface

I am new to opencv with android. I want to get back an array of Mat objects from JNI. I have created an application that sends some Mat objects from java to JNI. I can return int,long and other types from JNI. How would i return Mat object or array of Mat objects?
In this example it returns a long object

```
 JNIEXPORT jlong JNICALL
 Java_org_opencv_samples_fd_DetectionBasedTracker_nativeCreateObject
       (JNIEnv *, jclass, jstring, jint);
```

Comment: Why are you using JNI? Doesn't opencv already have Java bindings?

Comment: @JornVernee cause i want to create Native app with C++

Comment: In JNI everything boils Down to C, and in C you have pointers, So send `Mat` object you need to send pointer of that `Mat` object, which would be cast to `Mat` on  java side.

Comment: @ZdaR please explain it or give example

Comment: @ZdaR, on the C side your of course can work with pointers, but return Java object you can only via JVM API calls, i.e. you need _to bind_ returnable object to JVM (except primitive types, not arrays). You can't to use C pointers on Java side becouse of you not have directly access to memory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On java side you need to define `native` method like this:

```
public class DetectionBasedTracker {

    public static native Mat[] nativeCreateObject(String name, int count);
}
```

Your need to take information about `Mat` object from java and return new object as `jobject` and return array as `jobjectArray`:

```
JNIEXPORT jobjectArray JNICALL
Java_org_opencv_samples_fd_DetectionBasedTracker_nativeCreateObject
(JNIEnv *env, jclass cls, jstring str, jint count){

    // cls argument - is DetectionBasedTracker.class

    // take class info
    jclass matCls = env->FindClass("your/package/Mat");
    if (env->ExceptionOccurred())
        return NULL;

    // take constructor by signature
    const char* constructorSignature = "(Ljava/lang/String;)V";
    jmethodID constructor = env->GetMethodID(matCls, "<init>", constructorSignature);
    if (env->ExceptionOccurred())
        return NULL;

    // create java objects array
    jobjectArray matArray = env->NewObjectArray((jsize)count, matCls, NULL);
    for(jsize i = 0; i < count; i++){
        // create new object
        jobject mat = env->NewObject(matCls, constructor, /* constructor args */ str);
        // put object into array
        env->SetObjectArrayElement(matArray , i, mat);
    }

    return matArray;
}
```

To learn more about `constructorSignature` arguments look at [Java VM Type Signatures tabel](http://journals.ecs.soton.ac.uk/java/tutorial/native1.1/implementing/method.html)

**Note**: this is just a sample of creating Java objects via JNI. Using JNI only for creating instances of java objects - it's a bad practice.

Comment: thanks but how to access this jobject Array in java side

Comment: @Sophia, I wrote Java definition for JNI method. You can call it like other Java methods